# How to install Snaps with Ubuntu 16.04 on a custom kernel?

Tags: 16.04, kernel, snap

I can not install any Snap packages in Ubuntu 16.04 due to mounting snap core error. I have found the problem to be caused by using a custom kernel on Ubuntu. My kernel is a modified 4.4.0.20-36 for Surface Pro.
The output of any snap command is as follows:

```
$ sudo snap install notes
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Mount snap "core" (3604) ([start snap-core-3604.mount] failed with 
exit status 1: Job for snap-core-3604.mount failed. See "systemctl 
status snap-core-3604.mount" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
)
```

Output of systemctl status snap-core-3604.mount:

```
snap-core-3604.mount - Mount unit for core
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/snap-core-3604.mount; enabled; 
vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Sat 2017-12-16 22:22:23 
AEDT; 17min ago
    Where: /snap/core/3604
     What: /var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_3604.snap
   CGroup: /system.slice/snap-core-3604.mount
           └─7380 /bin/mount /var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_3604.snap 
/snap/core/3604 -t squashfs -o nodev,ro

Dec 16 22:17:52 rahn-Surface-Pro-3 systemd[1]: Mounting Mount unit for 
core...
Dec 16 22:19:22 rahn-Surface-Pro-3 systemd[1]: snap-core-3604.mount: 
Mounting timed out. Stopping.
Dec 16 22:20:53 rahn-Surface-Pro-3 systemd[1]: snap-core-3604.mount: 
Mounting timed out. Killing.
Dec 16 22:22:23 rahn-Surface-Pro-3 systemd[1]: snap-core-3604.mount: 
Mount process still around after SIGKILL. Ignoring.
Dec 16 22:22:23 rahn-Surface-Pro-3 systemd[1]: Failed to mount Mount 
unit for core.
Dec 16 22:22:23 rahn-Surface-Pro-3 systemd[1]: snap-core-3604.mount: 
Unit entered failed state.
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s because (afaik) upstream Linux sources don’t work with confinements. You could find the corresponding patch from [Ubuntu mainline kernel](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.14/) and build kernel with this patch.
Also, is there really no other kernel that will suit your needs and allow you to mount snaps?

Comment: I unfortunately can't, as I need a very specific kernel for the Surface Pro 3